# XNA HLSL texture masking effect does not use alpha in mask

Tags: c#, .net, xna, shader, hlsl

I am very new to HLSL to please bear with me...

This is the effect file:

```
sampler s0;
texture tex;
sampler tex_sampler = sampler_state{Texture = tex;};

float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0  
{  
    float4 color = tex2D(s0, coords);
    float4 tex_color = tex2D(tex_sampler, coords);

    if (tex_color.a) 
    {
        // SOMETHING GOES RIGHT HERE BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT
        return color;
    }
    return tex_color;
}  

technique Technique1  
{  
    pass Pass1  
    {  
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();  
    }  
}
```

The "tex" field is the mask.
The "tex_sampler" is the sampler for the mask.

The result contains either pixels with 1 or 0 alpha, but the mask is actually blurred and contains different alpha values. What should I add or change to make this do what I want? This works completely well otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to set renderstates in your technique.

```
    AlphaBlendEnable = true;
    SrcBlend = SrcAlpha;
    DestBlend = InvSrcAlpha;
```